# Unable to start Oracle Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oem

Had some passwords expire, and this knocked out my OEM (11g, SE).  Cleared this up, so that SYSMAN is not locked or expired (nor is DBSNMP, SYS, SYSTEM, all of which may or may not affect OEM, depending on various sources).

emctl start dbconsole gives me "failed" every time, and points me to a log directory containing a pile of stuff, where it's not obvious where to look, and where there are errors all over which may not be *the* error.

Tried various things on Oracle forums, but it seems like what I really need to know is, what is all this log information so that I can find a unique search string on the proper error?  I'm lost and not sure where to start.

Comment: A little more detail that might help:

*Has the server been rebooted?

*Any changes to the server lately?

*Can you look through the logs and post the parts of the log files that look most  relevant?

Comment: Have you changed the SYSMAN passwords?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that log directory is something like $ORACLE_HOME/hostname_SID/log. You should ckeck these files: emdctl.trc, emagent.*, emoms.*.
But the best thing i think you can do is backup those logs, delete them and then try to start dbconsole again. You will have a "clean slate" and will have to go through a lot less junk in logs to find the error.

Just my suggestion until you figure out which log actually stores your error.

Good luck.